# Android Studio crashes when I open xml file

Tags: android, android-studio

Please help me solve the following bug. After many attempts, I came to the conclusion that the point is not which program template I am using, but specifically in the xml files that have a design section (like activity_main.xml), it seems to me that I have already re-tried everything:

- installed new gradle
- deleted the .idea .gradle folders, files with the .iml extension, modules, settings.gradle files a million times
- Invalidate Caches / Restart
- changed the path for the SDK
- imported the project using "Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)"
- deleted all files along this path C: \ Users (Your UserName). AndroidStudio (version) and not only these files
- did chkdsk
  And it still doesn't work. The crash occurs only when opening xml files with design sections, on other files, including .xml, everything is ok. Has anyone come across a similar one?
  P.S. the error occurs by default along with the creation of a new template.

Comment: can you share your xml in the editor as well

Comment: @sashabeliy it's a standard activity_main.xml file from Empty Activity: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-C0l-EFXszqozY6xvRm22Sk-crcGMbYL/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

I seem to have figured out this error.
For those who will come across something similar in the future:
If I start a project and open an xml file that has a design in it (for example, activity_main.xml), then the program crashes. If you do not open this file, then everything is ok. You can even run it. The solution is as follows: you need to go to your project, while the main thing is that the xml files (similar to those I described above) are closed. Then start the MainActivity class with a debugger (set a breakpoint and then shift + F9) and then you need to walk a little (I mean step into with debugger) (maybe this is not necessary at all) through the files using F7 (step by step) and then open the file activity_main.xml (or any similar ) and voila! It will load and will not kick you out. Then you can work. You can even go out and go into the project and then it shouldn't crash anymore, but after the reboot your system you will need to repeat this process. I don’t know what it’s connected with at all, but it seems to me that the problem is that something prevents the .xml files (that is, the design tab) from loading and the program starts to crash with an unknown exception. And in order to solve this, you need to somehow run this file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the latest Android Studio version from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio) and reinstall all files  from beginning on your set-up

Comment: I tried to do it thousands of times, it didn't fix the problem

Comment: @ЕвгенийОрлов You getting any errors from android studio??

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Restore default settings
I think its work.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by installing Android Studio 4.2 RC 1 from https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.